# React Native ImagePicker showImagePicker alternative

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I've found out that with the newest version of `react-native-image-picker` the `showImagePicker` no longer exists. Is there any other native way we can still implement the functionality of showing us the ActionSheet of "Take photo", "Choose from library" (shown in image below) once the user wants to upload an image, or do we need to implement this ourselves?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they have removed it, you have to provide your own implementation to show actionsheet. From there you can choose to pick image from camera or gallery using launchCamera, launchImageLibrary functions.

Comment: Isn't there any other library that supports it? I've checked [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) but it's practically the same. Has anything changed at platform level that they had to remove it?